# CakePHP 4 Authentication plugin, allow access to all but admin directory

Tags: cakephp

I am building a very simple CMS backend for a website and I've opted to use CakePHP 4.  I want to know if there's a way to allow access to all sections of the website, unless they're in the Controller/Admin/ directory (where all administrative controls will occur).

In the documentation, it shows this example:

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    // for all controllers in our application, make index and view
    // actions public, skipping the authentication check
    $this->Authentication->addUnauthenticatedActions(['view', 'index']);

}
```

So I can add controller actions which are allowed without authentication, but since I've separated the login to the /Admin/ prefix, is there a way to just allow everything BUT what is in the /Admin/ prefix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement Request Authorization Middleware

**https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/request-authorization-middleware.html**

like:

```
public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->getParam('prefix') !== 'Admin') {
        return true;
    }

    if (
        $identity &&
        $request->getParam('prefix') === 'Admin' &&
        in_array($request->getParam('action'), ['add', 'edit'])
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```